# Simulating hand drawing on canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Is there a JavaScript library that simulates the canvas element but instead of creating straight lines, the lines created look 'free-form' or 'hand drawn'?

This would be very cool if it existed and it seems like someone should have already done it. Also if there are articles on the math involved in this, I would be interested because then I could try to implement this library myself.

Comment: I'm not really sure what exactly a library would take care of, but I once created a very trivial version of what you're describing: http://pimvdb.github.com/.

Comment: @pim I don't think that's what he means: He seems to want a library that can *programmatically* draw a line from one coordinate pair to another, and make that look hand-drawn.

Comment: is there any update to this? any new libraries since 3 years ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember reading something about doing this a couple of years ago. Incidentally that article was doing it in javascript on canvas. The idea was basically to draw the lines yourself pixel-by-pixel using something like Bresenham's line drawing algorithm but modify it to add some random deviations/pertubations in the line.

I'm not sure if this was the page I was reading at the time but this is what google brought up today: http://29a.ch/2010/2/10/hand-drawn-lines-algorithm-javascript-canvas-html5

Comment: This is what i was looking for, the quality seems to be a bit less than what i was hoping for but it's in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [article](http://29a.ch/2010/2/10/hand-drawn-lines-algorithm-javascript-canvas-html5) you mention: a cartoon style JS drawing library for SVG and HTML5 Canvas. It works as plugin for `Raphael.js`, `D3.js` or `SVG.js` or as lib for `Canvas`. It is called `comic.js` and can be found on [github](https://github.com/balint42/comic.js).

This what it can produce:

[image: comic.js screenshot]